# How to view the notification area in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I've just updated my machine from Debian Wheezy to Debian Testing. The GNOME version is 3.8.4 but I have an annoying problem.

The bottom notification area is gone and I don't know how to make it reappear. I mean the notification area where minimized icons of the programs are shown.

How to view the notification area in GNOME?

Comment: ahrrrrrr!! I didn't know that! But this is a new feature of the recent gnome right? Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: You must start mouse movement in the middle of the screen, go to the lower border and CONTINUE moving down the mouse until the panel appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is known as Message tray in GNOME 3. It contains all the notifications that you have not acted upon or that permanently reside in it. It also shows the status icons of your running programs (which uses it).

The message tray is hidden by default. It appears when you move your mouse to the bottom screen edge and let the mouse rest there for a short period of time, or press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. You can close the message tray by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> again or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The new message tray was added in GNOME 3.6 with lots of improvements over the old one. See the [release notes of GNOME 3.6](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-message-tray.html.en) for more information.

Comment: weird is that if I move the mouse to the bottom-right corner, nothing appears. Nevertheless, the `Super` + `M` combination works fine!

Comment: @matteo: It would take a bit of getting used to when using the mouse, but it works :)

Comment: not so sure about it... should the behavior be the same as for the upper left corner? if so, I'm pretty sure it doesn't work

Comment: @matteo Moving your mouse to the upper left corner brings in the Activities Overview, not the message tray. So, it is expected to be different :)

Comment: Yes, I know that the upper left corner is related to the Activities Overview, but you said that moving the mouse to the bottom right corner would open the Message tray right?

Comment: @matteo Message tray would open if you move the mouse to bottom edge of the screen and keep it still for a moment (doesn't matter right-corner, left-corner or middle - it should be in the bottom edge of the screen).

Comment: I don't want to be boring, but it doesn't wor.. :( Could be related to the fact that I'm running debian testing (so not a stable version)?

Comment: @matteo Are you using some Gnome shell extension? If so, it is possible that they might be causing the problems. Anyways, Super + M works for you. That is what I would recommend to use..

Comment: yep I'm using them, but maybe you are right... thanks anyway for your help, Super + M works!

Comment: @matteo it's not just you, on my vanilla installation moving the mouse doesn't work too. Super + M does the trick luckily

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you have Dash to Dock extension installed, the tray is only actionable by Super + M

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I must do some "pressure" with my mouse on the bottom edge of the screen.
With Dash to Dock extension Super + M and "pressure" are works.

Comment: Can you describe how the "pressure" you refer to differs from the resting the mouse at the bottom of the screen that Aditya mentioned in their answer?

Comment: For me the message tray becomes visible if I move the pointer "past the bottom", eg. keep moving the mouse even at the edge.

Comment: Whether it's "pressure" or a timed delay depends on Xorg version. (Delay was used before Xorg added the 'barrier' feature.)